# Cluster Performance Visualisation

Tags: hadoop, raspberry-pi, cluster-computing, visualization, raspberry-pi3

I've recently just built and configured a (8-Pi) Raspberry Pi 3 Hadoop cluster, as a personal project over the summer. My goal for the project is to demonstrate how cluster computing works to kids and teens (primarily aged between 12-18 years old).

What would be the most effective way in which I am able to visually compare the performance of one-node against the performance of the devices within the cluster (keeping in mind the target audience that this demonstration is aimed at)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, Hadoop has no such vizualization tools.

You can use any combination of

- Apache Ambari
- [Netdata](https://my-netdata.io/)
- Ganglia
- [Grafana](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/2558/how-to-use-grafana-to-visualize-metrics-exposed-by.html) w/ either Ambari or Prometheus + JMX Exporters

But overall, you'll want to be familiar with gathering JMX metrics because those will tell you what is taking over the Java memory space of the cluster.

Comment: Hi again Cricket, are you aware if any of these tools can have a process assigned as the base of the metric to gather? E.g. If I am able to run a MapReduce program, and they are able to report back the relative progress (0-100%) the nodes / cluster has made so far? My idea was to run an application allocated to a single node, and the same application across a cluster of nodes, and to visually compare the progress between the two.

Comment: I think you can get access to that from the YARN ResourceManager Rest API... At least, that is how Hue does it. It would need to be some custom Javascript HTTP fetch thing with a loop, though. I'm not sure of any existing tools like that